# Testing my CNN on a small set of image but training has no effect

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I constructed a CNN to recognize 9 classes of gestures in images of 224x224x3. I try to test its functionality by training it on 16 images and see if it overfits to 100 accuracy. Here is my network

```
    import torch.nn as nn
    class learn_gesture(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(learn_gesture, self).__init__()
            self.name = "gesture_learner"
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=20, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)                 
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=20, out_channels=50, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)
            self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=50, out_channels=100, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)
            self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=100, out_channels=200, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)
            self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=200, out_channels=400, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)                
            self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
            self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
            self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
            self.pool4 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
            self.pool5 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(7*7*400, 10000)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10000, 3000)
            self.fc3 = nn.Linear(3000, 9)
    
        def forward(self, x):
            x = self.pool1(F.relu(self.conv1(x))) # gives 112*20
            x = self.pool2(F.relu(self.conv2(x))) # gives 56*50
            x = self.pool3(F.relu(self.conv3(x))) # gives 28*100
            x = self.pool4(F.relu(self.conv4(x))) # gives 14*200
            x = self.pool5(F.relu(self.conv5(x))) # gives 7*400
            x = x.view(-1, 7*7*400)
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
            return F.softmax(self.fc3(x), dim=1)
```

And here is the training code:

```
    overfit_model = learn_gesture()
    num_epochs = 200   #set it high so that it will converge
    ## loss function and optimizer
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()    
    optimizer = optim.SGD(over_model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)       #optimizer is SGD with momentum

    ## set up some empty np arrays to store our result for plotting later
    train_err = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    train_loss = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    ################################################ train the network
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        total_train_loss = 0
        total_train_err = 0
        total_epoch = 0
        for i, data in enumerate(smallLoader, 0):
            inputs, labels = data
            outputs = over_model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            corr = (determine_corr(outputs, labels))    # get a list of bool representing right or wrong predictions in the batch
            total_train_err += corr.count(False)        
            total_train_loss += loss.item()
            total_epoch += len(labels)
        train_err[epoch] = float(total_train_err) / total_epoch
        train_loss[epoch] = float(total_train_loss) / (i+1)
        print(("Epoch {}: Train err: {}, Train loss: {}").format(
                   enter code hereepoch + 1,
                   train_err[epoch],
                   train_loss[epoch]))
```

The training has no effect, and both the accuracy and loss has no improvement either. I just absolutely can't figure out where the error is. Any help is greatly appreciated!

###############  Update ##############

I got rid of the softmax in the forward function. Surprisingly, the performance of the model hasn't changed much. And I notice that some elements in the output now are negative and the elements across all classes do not add to 1. Is this supposed to happen?
output:

```
tensor([[ 0.0165, -0.0041,  0.0043,  0.0017,  0.0238,  0.0329, -0.0265, -0.0224,
     -0.0187],
    [ 0.0163, -0.0044,  0.0036,  0.0028,  0.0248,  0.0334, -0.0268, -0.0218,
     -0.0194],
    [ 0.0161, -0.0046,  0.0041,  0.0019,  0.0240,  0.0333, -0.0266, -0.0223,
     -0.0192],
    [ 0.0190, -0.0044,  0.0035,  0.0015,  0.0244,  0.0322, -0.0267, -0.0223,
     -0.0187],
    [ 0.0174, -0.0048,  0.0033,  0.0021,  0.0251,  0.0328, -0.0257, -0.0225,
     -0.0190],
    [ 0.0175, -0.0041,  0.0033,  0.0031,  0.0241,  0.0329, -0.0264, -0.0222,
     -0.0192],
    [ 0.0168, -0.0042,  0.0033,  0.0022,  0.0251,  0.0335, -0.0269, -0.0225,
     -0.0195],
    [ 0.0163, -0.0047,  0.0037,  0.0030,  0.0243,  0.0336, -0.0265, -0.0227,
     -0.0192],
    [ 0.0165, -0.0043,  0.0038,  0.0026,  0.0242,  0.0337, -0.0264, -0.0222,
     -0.0191],
    [ 0.0163, -0.0051,  0.0038,  0.0016,  0.0236,  0.0338, -0.0258, -0.0223,
     -0.0195],
    [ 0.0173, -0.0037,  0.0038,  0.0018,  0.0236,  0.0322, -0.0269, -0.0225,
     -0.0191],
    [ 0.0174, -0.0044,  0.0031,  0.0019,  0.0241,  0.0334, -0.0266, -0.0224,
     -0.0200],
    [ 0.0164, -0.0038,  0.0034,  0.0029,  0.0245,  0.0342, -0.0269, -0.0225,
     -0.0200],
    [ 0.0173, -0.0046,  0.0036,  0.0021,  0.0245,  0.0328, -0.0264, -0.0221,
     -0.0192],
    [ 0.0168, -0.0046,  0.0034,  0.0025,  0.0248,  0.0336, -0.0262, -0.0222,
     -0.0194],
    [ 0.0166, -0.0051,  0.0033,  0.0015,  0.0234,  0.0331, -0.0270, -0.0218,
     -0.0186]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)
Epoch 199: Train err: 0.8125, Train loss: 2.1874701976776123
```

Answer (score 3):

1. It seems that you are using a model named `overfit_model` where you pass `over_model.parameters()` to the optimizer:

   ```
   optimizer = optim.SGD(over_model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
   ```

   Should be replaced with `ovrefit_model.parameters()`.
2. You are setting your gradients to *zeros* right ***after*** you back propagate, where it should be done beforehand. So, the following lines:

   ```
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
   ```

   Should be replaced with:

   ```
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
   ```
3. There is no need to call `F.softmax` in

   ```
   return F.softmax(self.fc3(x), dim=1)
   ```

   since you are using [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) that calls [`F.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy) which [natively bundles `log_softmax` before calling `nll_loss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/functional.html#cross_entropy)

   ```
   return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input. I tried it, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, I updated my question to reflect what happened after I removed softmax

Comment: If you want to use `ReLU` why are you using the `F.relu`? This is only functional behavior that doesn't back propagate, `nn.ReLU` should be used instead

Comment: I used F.relu because https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~lczhang/360/lec/w02/training.html uses F.relu. To be honest, I think I get the ground idea of  neural network, but the Pytorch API and even Python is quiet new to me. I read through the documentation of both nn.ReLU and F.relu, it seems that using either would achieve the same. and which to use purely depend on style, https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/whats-the-difference-between-nn-relu-vs-f-relu/27599. It makes sense according to my understanding because weights that we are trying to train exist in the layer that we defined and not the activation

Comment: They are not really the same. In the functional version, you will have to handle the weights yourself.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should remove `softmax` before 'nn.CrossEntropyLoss' as other answers discovered.

Now the actual problem you are on is, your neural CNN model is **very deep** but your dataset is very small. Under this condition, either you may need thousands of epoches, or even the model can't converge at all. If you can increase your dataset or use less deep CNN model, you can overcome the *convergence problem* you are facing now.

But you don't want to change those, here is my suggestion:
Quoting from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140811/how-large-should-the-batch-size-be-for-stochastic-gradient-descent)

> The most basic method of hyper-parameter search is to do a grid search over the learning rate and batch size to find a pair which makes the network converge.

Let's talk about batch size. If your dataset is very small, model is too deep, then moderate batch size (i.e. 32 or 16) may not work. As you want to test a over fitting model, **try with very small batch size (4 or 8)**. This will help to find a local maxima for small number of samples quickly.

If you have already tried this, try with increasing the learning rate.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input. I decreased my batch size to 4, and decreased the depth of my model by increasing pooling's stride and kernal size. It still took ~150 epoch iters for the models to predict right on all 4 images. Now I need to use my model on a bigger set of data. How can I increase the performance of my model? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not reducing because you are using CrossEntropyLoss after softmax, so basically you are just reducing the amount of gradient back flowing

Just remove the softmax, and it should work

(Will edit it to add the reason later)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, I updated my question to reflect what happened after I removed softmax

Comment: Why is there a different object passed into the optimizer? You are initializing your neural network as overfit_model but you are passing over_model in the optimizer??

Comment: Also, gradients can flow using functional api too. No need to change that..

here is a proof of that https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-torch-nn-and-torch-nn-functional/33597/6

Comment: over_ model is a typo sorry for that

Comment: Hey, the output could be positive or negative... if you pass the output to a softmax function, you will get the output that sums to 1 and isn't zero. Also, it should have worked after the softmax fix

Comment: Also, there is no improvement at all?